# How to aggregate extract and join workfrow in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have tables like below.

And I successed to extract `T2` and I would like to join other tables and aggregate workflow.

First I would like to subtract all customers who has `product = A`

```
product  customer
A        A
B        A
C        B
B        B
A        C
B        C
.        .
.        .
.        .
```

Therefore `T2`is extracted from table like below.

```
product  customer
A        A
B        A
A        C
B        C
```

By below code,I can get `T2`

```
WITH T2 AS (
    SELECT t.*,
        COUNT(CASE WHEN product = 'A' THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY customer) AS a_cnt
    FROM yourTable t
)

SELECT product, customer
FROM T2
WHERE a_cnt > 0;
```

Further more 
I would like to join `T3` like

```
customer age
A        10
B        20
C        30
```

Therefore My desired result is like below

```
product  customer  age
A        A         10 
B        A         10
A        C         30
B        C         30
```

Are there any sophisticated way to aggregate workflow?

If you have any opinion,please let me know.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` as follows:

```
SELECT T1.PRODUCT, T1.CUSTOMER, T3.AGE
FROM T1 T1 JOIN T3 T3 ON T1.CUSTOMER = T3.CUSTOMER
WHERE EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                 FROM T1 T
                WHERE T.CUSTOMER = T1.CUSTOMER
                  AND T.PRODUCT = 'A')
```

Comment: Thanks and nice use of `EXISTS`, I could get `T2` and I would like to join `T3`. My desired result is to aggregate each workflow . `T2` is `extracted` from original tables. is it reproductive ? Thanks

Comment: T2 is not needed in this solution.